# iframe using nginx reverse proxy

Tags: html, nginx, iframe, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

i am trying to iframe amazon.com but it refuses to connect even after reverse proxy using nginx.

```
server {
       listen 443;

       server_name www.amazon.com amazon.com;

       root /var/www/example.com;
       index index.html;

       location / {
                   proxy_pass  http://140.82.3.69;
    proxy_set_header Host http://140.82.3.69;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_hide_header 'x-frame-options';
    proxy_set_header x-frame-options allowall;
       }
}
```

i am using this type of configs.

here is test url: http://140.82.3.69/

i am facing issue it's still refused to connect as it shows on regular hosting.

Comment: Hi there, did you able to fix the problem ? Maybe its because https doesnt allow to do that.